# Pygame in-place methodes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

What are the differences of in_place functions to non-ip ones and why do they exist?
When should one use for instance `move()`,`inflate()` and when to use `move_ip()`,`inflate_ip()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The in place function work, well, in place; they change the `Rect` you call them on, while the non-in place functions return new instances of the `Rect` class with the according changes.

You can use them anytime you actually want to change a `Rect`, e.g. you have a `Sprite` and want to move it, you can use

```
s = SomeSpriteClass()
s.rect.move_ip(100, 0)
```

instead of

```
s = SomeSpriteClass()
s.rect = s.rect.move(100, 0)
```

to move the `Sprite` 100 pixels to the right.

You would use the non-in place functions when you don't want to actually change the `Rect`, e.g. when you only want to do some calculations, like implementing a camera function.

Comment: Does an `ip` function thus also reserve on resources since it doesn't make and return a new copy of the object?